# Taken to random websites when clicking on links

Tags: security

My girlfriend was browsing the web last night on this wireless connection and clicked my Google home page, only to get the ''Untrusted site'' page. I then went to yahoo.com and clicked on the youtube link only to be taken to some iranian website.

Clicked on another websearch link and it took me to a totally different website.
Did an AV scan - all clean. Did an MBAR scan - all clean.
I checked my connection info and it said ''Unidentified Network''. It's now back to my normal connection name with everything working fine.

There's 2 routers in the place i'm staying. Since they put the 2nd router in i quite often have to turn off both routers to get a wireless connection.

Had one of those ''Another computer on this network has the same IP address as this computer'' pop ups today.

Any ideas?

Comment: It sounds like you connected to a rogue network. You should disable SSID broadcasting then configure all your devices manually to connect to the correct network.  Be sure the configuration password and the password to connect to the network is secure enough that it cannot be access by anyone except you.

Comment: Probably a good time to change the SSID, so you can immediately tell if you're connecting to the rogue network. Whilst you're at it, make sure you're not using WEP.

Comment: Please explain how the 2 routers operate. Why would turning them off enable you to get a wireless signal? Do you mean you reboot them? Is one of them merely a signal booster?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your host file can be hacked by replacing the legit IP address with a malicious one. The host file is basically a local DNS, where your machine matches the name of the site you type in into the IP address the computer uses to send you to a website. Google host file for the pathway, or if you have the time (and you should) go [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zRysni9ND2w) for an enlightening and somewhat comprehensive video on DNS and DNS hacking. Worth the time!

Comment: Thanks for the help people! I'm staying in a hotel in SE Asia, and the 2nd router was put in as the signal from the original was poor. If it's something to do with the local DNS would changing to the free ''secure DNS'' that my AV provides solve this problem? thanks again